# jQuery Mobile Flip Switch Styling

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I have found tht it is possible to customize the font, color and font-size of a jQuery Mobile flip switch with the following code

**The CSS**

```
.contel *{font-family:arial !important;color:red !important;font-size:0.8em !important}
```

**The Markup**

```
<div class="contel">
 <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
<option value="off">Off</option>
<option value="on">On</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

which is very nice but what I need to do is to apply such styling on a case by case basis at run time rather than from static CSS.

The question then boils down to this - is there a way to achieve this via jQuery?  I have tried things along the lines of

```
$.each($('.contel > *'),function(ndx,e){$(e).css('fontFamily','arial')});
```

but it has no effect whatsoever.  I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked deeper  under the covers after I posted this query and found a few interesting things.

- Firstly, the jQuery > selector only returns child elements.  In the case of the flip switch the element to be styled is actually a grandchild.  So my code should have been

  $.each($('.contel > * > span'),function(ndx,e){$(e).css('fontFamily','arial')});

since the grandchild in question that requires styling is actually a span element.  But this is where things start getting curious

That line of code turns

```
<span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%; ">On</span>
```

into

On

i.e. gives the element an inline styling.

If instead I define a class

```
.georgia{font-family:georgia !important}
```

the new code is

```
<span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all georgia" role="img" style="width: 0%; ">On</span>
```

i.e. the elment gets a new class tagged on to it.

Contrary to what the jQuery Mobile documentation suggests this upstyles the element as expected, even without issuing a slider('refresh').  However, the css modification that gives the element additional inline styling does not.

It is not clear to me why this could be happening.  Hopefully, there is someone out here who has a better understanding of CSS3 and jQuery who can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

why not making a class and then when the event is triggered just

```
.addClass() ;
```

?